# Rope tension between two objects

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

[image]

Let me explain the picture just to make sure. Object with mass 2 kg is being pulled with a force of F = 14.4 N. The whole system has an acceleration of a = 2.8 m/s^2. The friction coefficient between the objects and the ground is k = 0.2 What is the tension in the rope?
So the question is simple I believe but I can't understand the concept of tension in the rope (red line). Also if it helps I have a solution for the problem, it says that the tension is 4.8 N. Can someone please elaborate this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to think what are the forces acting on block with mass 1kg .The forces in horizontal direction are:-

1.friction

2.tension from rope

Now tension is something very common ,you just take a rope and hang a object from it ,it does not fall because tension balances the force of gravity.Basically all you need to produce tension is a rope and a pulling mechanism and you produce tension at the other end.

Since you know the acceleration of this block you can apply F = ma and find the tension.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your answer to the problem with the blocks. Can you please show the calculation ?

Comment: please be more specific about what you don't understand

Comment: How to calculate the tension. Apparently, it's equal to 4.8 N. No matter what I do I can't get that result.

Comment: (tension)-(friction)= (1) * (2.8),friction=0.2*1*10

Comment: lol i was doing something totally different trying to get the net force on one side and on the other and then add that up. Thank you a lot!

Comment: you are most welcome